$\lambda:=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n|b_i|^2}$ makes $\sum_{i=1}^n\left|a_i-\lambda\overline{b_i}\right|^2$ as small as possible. Ahlfors.
I am reading "Complex Analysis Third Edition" by Lars V. Ahlfors.
Let $a_i,b_i\in\mathbb{C}$ for all $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$.
Then
$$\left|\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i\right|^2\leq\sum_{i=1}^n |a_i|^2\sum_{i=1}^n |b_i|^2.$$
The author proved the above inequality holds as follows:
If $\sum_{i=1}^n|b_i|^2=0$, then the above inequality holds.
Suppose $\sum_{i=1}^n|b_i|^2\neq 0$.
Let $\lambda:=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n|b_i|^2}$.
Then, $$0\leq\sum_{i=1}^n\left|a_i-\lambda\overline{b_i}\right|^2=\sum_{i=1}^n|a_i|^2+|\lambda|^2\sum_{i=1}^n|b_i|^2-2\Re\overline{\lambda}\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_i=\sum_{i=1}^n|a_i|^2-\frac{\left|\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_i\right|^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n|b_i|^2}.$$
The author wrote about the choice of $\lambda$:

This choice is not arbitrary, but it is dictated by the desire to make the expression $\sum_{i=1}^n\left|a_i-\lambda\overline{b_i}\right|^2$ as small as possible.

How to prove $\lambda:=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n|b_i|^2}$ makes the expression $\sum_{i=1}^n\left|a_i-\lambda\overline{b_i}\right|^2$ as small as possible?
